# Vi undo updated file?

Tags: vim

I just deleted a bunch of text on a file and saved it.

Is it possible to recover the older version of file back?

I know I should have taken a backup, just trying my luck.

Comment: Is there a `filename~` file in your working directory? I mean a file with the same name as the one you edited but with a `~` at the end.

Comment: What programme were you using?

Comment: @terdon the temp file normally only exists if you haven't exited `vi` or exit it improperly (like a `kill -9`). Chances are this change was saved and exited properly.

Comment: @ToDo he tagged `vi`, so probably that.

Comment: @Dave that's a backup, not a temp. It should be created when the file is changed past a certain threshold, normally.

Comment: @terdon No, I cant find any file with a `~` at the end.

Comment: @ToDo I was using `vi`.

Comment: In that case, no, I don't think there's anything you can do.

Comment: Not that it would help here, but most people thinking they use vi actually use vim these days.

Comment: @jlliagre agreed, normally `vi` is aliased to `vim`

Comment: @jlliagre actually, it might help if he's running `vim` rather than `vi`.  `vim` saves the last few deletes in registers that are, in turn, saved in `~/.viminfo` (which can be viewed with `less` - search for `^"`).   these can be pasted back in to a file with, e.g., `"1p` (for register 1).  if he did one big delete, or only a few small ones he might be able to recover the entire text.

Comment: Of course, the `.viminfo` file could potentially leak confidential information.  e.g. I got into the habit of deleting root's .viminfo when building VM images.

Comment: @cas Indeed, that's an interesting approach. You probably should post it as an answer.

Comment: @cas Even if the OP isn't using vim, other people in the same situation but using vim might find this question by searching the web, and would probably miss the solution you suggest if it stays only a buried comment. Moreover, if you post your answer, I'll vote it up ! I'm sure you badly need to increase your reputation here ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using `vim`, you may be able to recover some or all of your deleted text because vim stores the 9 most recent deletions in registers 1 to 9, which are saved to a file called `.viminfo` in your home directory when you exit `vim`.

This registers saved in `~/.viminfo` are global, for all files that have been edited, **NOT** one set per edited file.  So if you've edited other file and deleted any lines, some or all of your deleted text will be gone.

If you haven't edited and deleted (many) lines from other files yet, there's a good chance (some of) your deleted lines will still be there.

You can check to see if your text is still in those registers with the `:registers` command in `vim`.

1. run `vim filename`  (where filename is the name of the file you accidentally cleared)
2. Type `:registers` (or the abbreviated form, just `:reg`) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
3. Examine the output to see if something that looks like your text is there.

e.g. on my system, I see something like the following in `vim`:

```
:reg
--- Registers ---
""   ^J
"0   ^J
"1   You can check to see if your text is still in those registers with the :registers command in vim.^J
"2   If you haven't edited and deleted lines from other files yet, there's a good chance your deleted lines will still be there.^J^J
"3   If you are using vim, you may be able to recover some or all of your deleted text because vim stores the most recent 9 deletion in registers 1 to 9, which are saved to a file called .viminf
"4   ^J
...
...
...
```

Note: `""` is the "unnamed" register and always contains the value of the most recent yank or delete, and `"0` is the current yank register.  For more info, see [How do I use vim registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-do-i-use-vim-registers). Google also found me this [blog post](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/advanced-vim-registers/) which describes it well.

There's also the built-in help with `:help registers` and, of course, http://www.vim.org/,  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki and https://vi.stackexchange.com/ for more general `vim` info.

4. If you see some of the deleted text in a register, then type <kbd>"</kbd>, followed by the number of the register, and then <kbd>p</kbd> to paste it into the current buffer at the current location.

   e.g. If I wanted to restore registers 1 and 2 above, I'd type:

   <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

   and those registers would be pasted into my current editing buffer.

NOTE: as soon as you type anything, like `"` to start pasting a register, the `:registers` display will vanish.  So either make a note of which registers you want to restore, or just type `:registers` as often as you need to remind yourself.

Comment: I was not able to retrieve the whole text but I could see some text that I had recently deleted. Very interesting approach. Thanks.

Comment: approximately five hours and a headache saved. thanks!