# How do I recover data from xfs and ext4 filesystem

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, vi, xfs

Hi guys I just wanna know if there’s a simple command to recover a simple data file such as vi text in ext4 and xfs filesystem in linux

Comment: Have you tried [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)?

Comment: u mean testkdisk right? I’ll try that thx

Comment: It's one of the tools in the testdisk suite, yes.

Comment: You can use `debugfs`  to recover `ext4` files. Otherwise you need third-party utilities.

Comment: @fpmurphy Those would be a lot more difficult to use.

Comment: @fpmurphy can u also recover xfs files with debugfs? If not, any suggestions like debugfs to recover data from xfs?

Comment: @Tae Debug tools like `debugfs` are only useful if you know the file's inode. If you don't, you'll probably want to use photorec instead.

Comment: @forest i googled debugfs and it also shows the date when I deleted so I think i can find the matched inode :) but can it be used with xfs too? I’ll try both though thx

Comment: I don't think it can. XFS has its own debug tools. The `debugfs` utility is specific to ext2/3/4.

Comment: @forest then i should try photorec that can be used in both filesystem :)

Comment: If the file's vi .swp file is available, it might be recoverable with `vi -r filename` . A recoverable copy may also be available in /var/tmp.  If you're using `vim`, you may be able to recover some or all of the file from registers in ~/.viminfo - see [Vi undo updated file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290515).  Note that I used the words "might" and "may" - none of these are guaranteed to work....but they do give a reasonable chance to recover at least some of the file.

Comment: @cas oh, so u mean just vi -r filename can restore deleted vi files? thx

Comment: [R-Linux](https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/Download.shtml) can recover any type of specific file you search on a disk if this one hasn't been erased with zeros or overwrited.

Comment: `vi -r` can't recover deleted files, but it can often recover files that you were editing when vi (or the system) crashed.  If you want to recover deleted files, you'd best have a backup. or at least a snapshot-capable filesystem like btrfs or zfs. anything else is a gamble.

Comment: @Tae.  No, `debugfs` does not work with XFS.  Sometimes you can recover files with `xfs_db`  and `xfs_repair`.